# How to drop my Foreign key in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate to generate my schema. Hibernate create the following sql instruction

```
alter table Person add index FKA126572FF5D5DSE (job_id), add constraint FKA126572FF5D5DSE foreign key (job_id) references Job(id)
```

This sql was executed in my database and the index exists.I would like just to remove the index and its associated constraint.
Is it the following sufficient ?

```
alter table Person drop foreign key FKA126572FF5D5DSE ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why's the index called FKA126572FF5D5DSE?

Comment: The name of the index is generated using Hibernate default Rules. I don't need to have a specific name

Comment: If you want to drop the index as well you need to do it explicitly. Only if you drop the table then the index will be also dropped implicitly.

Comment: @zaratustra what is missing in my drop instruction ?

Comment: @Pracede Did you try it and it doesn't work, or are you asking just from curiosity? ^^

Comment: Yes i've tried it. It does not work. It just delete the foreign key but the index remains. So to delete Index and Foreign Key, I have to do 2 instruction drop foreign key first then drop index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drop the foreign key and its index you need to execute:

```
alter table t1 drop FOREIGN KEY FKA126572FF5D5DSE;
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP INDEX FKA126572FF5D5DSE;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ead88)